# Mobile issue – website isn't properly detecting screen size

Tags: themes, child-theme, mobile, responsive

my question concerns this website (currently on my staging server): https://sunstonebookkeeping.markhannondesign.com

The theme is a child theme of a parent theme I created with Underscores and Bootstrap. I am getting some odd behavior when I view the website on my phone. See the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot from Chrome Developer tools]

If I click another page in the menu, the website corrects itself and fits properly on the screen. However when I turn my phone to landscape, the full-size desktop version loads. Again, when I click another page in the menu, the website resizes itself to properly fit the screen.

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary menu container is set to `left: 5000px;` witch stretches the width of the page. You can find this style directive in *...themes/sunstone-bookkeeping/css/mobile.css on line 66*.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
.nav-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5000px;
}
```

One way to fix this is to add the following styles to the parent element:

```
.menu-menu-1-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This solution shouldn't mess with other styles.

The proper way of applying this kind of changes is described here: [child themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). In the **style.css** file of your child theme you can safely add the solution that I proposed. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I was beginning to suspect the absolute positioning as the culprit. Appreciate the simple solution.